# Куда программа сохраняет файлы при автозапуске

Tags: linux, ubuntu, автозапуск

У меня написан бот для Telegram и установлен на VPS. Программа сохраняет данные в файл в той же директории и при перезапуске считывает их. 
Я поставил программу на автозапуск по [этой инструкции](https://losst.ru/avtozagruzka-linux#104010741090108610791072107510881091107910821072_10891082108810801087109010861074_1074_Linux) (Параграф **АВТОЗАГРУЗКА СКРИПТОВ В LINUX**):

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/runscript.service
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/local/script.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

$ sudo chmod a=r,u+w /lib/systemd/system/runscript.service
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable runscript.service
```

Автозапуск работает, программа работает, данные сохраняются и считываются. Но не понятно куда сохраняются.

Вопрос в том, куда сохраняются данные при таком раскладе.

Comment: find / -name "имя файла данных" и ждать

Comment: @KoVadim это было первое, что попробовал. Но в ответ я получаю огрооооомный список Permission denied, хотя сижу из под root.

Comment: не во все каталоги так просто можно заходить. даже руту. Но можно и по другому - с помощью ps  смотрим pid процесса, а потом lsof -p <pid> смотрим список открытых файлов

Comment: хм, файл открывается, происходит запись и он сразу закрывается. Но можно попробовать. Интересная штука, не знал. Спасибо

Comment: если бот ваш, то Вы всегда можете распечатать текущий рабочий каталог (getcwd) - и печатать его в файл с известным именем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы специально не заморачивались выбором места для сохранения файлов - то, скорее всего, они сохраняются в текущую директорию, которая в свою очередь по умолчанию является директорией пользователя. Если программа работает от рута - значит, файлы надо искать в `/root`

Но, вообще говоря, чем искать где-то там файлы, к тому же перемешанные с другими файлами от других программ - лучше настроить сохранения файлов в правильном месте.

В идеале, ваш бот должен использовать переменные окружения `RUNTIME_DIRECTORY`, `STATE_DIRECTORY`, `CACHE_DIRECTORY`, `LOGS_DIRECTORY` и `CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY` для размещения файлов. А эти директории, в свою очередь, должны создаваться следующими директивами:

- `RuntimeDirectory=имя` создаст папку по пути `/run/имя` для хранения временных файлов, автоматически удаляемых при остановке программы;
- `StateDirectory=имя` создаст папку по пути `/var/lib/имя` для постоянного хранения генерируемых в процессе работы важных файлов;
- `CacheDirectory=имя` создаст папку по пути `/var/cache/имя` для хранения генерируемых в процессе работы необязательных файлов (то есть таких файлов, которые можно удалить для очистки свободного места не поломав программу);
- `LogsDirectory=имя` создаст папку по пути `/var/log/имя` для хранения логов;
- `ConfigurationDirectory=имя` создаст папку по пути `/etc/имя` для хранения настроек.

---

Однако, если это всё для вас слишком сложно, или просто нет необходимости как-то интегрироваться с системой - можно пойти по простому пути. Просто добавьте в юнит директиву `WorkingDirectory=/путь/к/папке` и ваш бот, скорее всего, будет сохранить все файлы в указанной вами папке.

Обычно такие папки "всё в одном" размещают в `/opt`.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень ценная информация!

Answer (score 3):

очевидно, что если в конфигурации сервиса вы не добавляли инструкций по запуску исполняемого файла от имени какого-нибудь пользователя, то запускается он от имени пользователя `root`.

соотвественно, если в вашем исполняемом файле указан *относительный* (а не абсолютный) путь к файлу, и внутри скрипта не происходит смена текущего каталога (или что-нибудь аналогичное), то ищите его в домашнем каталоге пользователя `root`. обычно — `/root`, уточнить можно, например, так:

```
$ getent passwd root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

шестое поле — это путь к домашнему каталогу.

---

в особо тяжёлых случаях можно посмотреть, на какой каталог указывает ссылка `/proc/идентификатор_процесса/cwd`. этот каталог и является текущим для процесса с указанным идентификатором на данный момент.

Comment: В общем, по этому пути пусто.

Comment: @LeonNash, 1. комментарии не подходят для форматированного текста. лушче добавить его в текст вопроса. 2. есть файлы/каталоги, начинающиеся с точки. см. вывод `ls -a`

Comment: Второй подход помог! Я нашёл тот самый файл. Но если не сложно, объясните, как происходит так, что при перезапуске сервера, программа успешно считывает данные. Неужели несколько раз вышло так, что pid был тем же самым? Или как это работает?

Comment: @LeonNash, у каждого процесса есть свойство «текущий каталог» (см. символические ссылки `/proc/идентификатор_процесса/cwd`). дочерний процесс наследует это свойство от родительского. т.е., какой каталог был текущим для родительского процесса в момент вызова `fork()`, такой и будет текущим для дочернего (в вашем случае родительский — это `systemd`, дочерний — интерпретатор вашего скрипта). естественно, любой процесс в любой момент может поменять **свой** текущий каталог с помощью `chdir()`

Comment: @LeonNash, не стоит полагаться на то, что ваш процесс будет **всегда** запускаться с одним и тем же каталогом в качестве текущего. потому имеет смысл либо писать в файл по абсолютному пути, либо в начале программы изменить текущий каталог на что-то нужное.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, очень помогли